# Crankset cassette compatilibility

Tags: crankset, cassette, chainring, compatibility

I'm looking to upgrade my crankset, currently a 48/34 Shimano R460, to a GRX RX600. What is not clear to me is whether the RX, which is designed to work with an 11-cogs cassette, will work fine also with my 10-cogs cassette.
Thanks in advance for you help good people!

Answer (score 8):

There are two flavours of FC-RX600, namely [FC-RX600-10](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-10-speed/FC-RX600-10.html) and [FC-RX600-11](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/FC-RX600-11.html). You want the 10 speed one for a 10-speed drivetrain. The cassette does not matter, the chainrings and the front derailleur only see your 10-speed chain.

You should also get the GRX front derailleur. The chainline is different. That could also cause issues when interacting with the back but chances are that it will work fine. The chain will just come to the real derailleur from a slighly different angle so some gear combinations that were not noisy before might become so.

You might get it all working with your current front derailleur, but it is officially not compatible. Many people tried various combinations, though. The shifter actuation ratio should be OK if you have the more recent Tiagra 4700 and not the older ones.

Comment: So ... they could buy both the FD and crankset, then install just the crankset and see if it works with their FD. A road FD may not have enough travel to shift to the big ring, as the GRX chainline is a few mm outward, but it's possible it works. If it works (the OP should check this under full power on the road), then they could return the unused GRX FD.